# Diff command for two files and output to third

Tags: shell, diff, csh

I just a have a small problem with comparing two files with the diff command in a shell script. Say I have two ascii files, file1.txt and file2.txt, with contents:

file1.txt

```
blah/blah2/content.fits/  
blah3/blah4/content2.fits/  
blah5/blah6/content3.fits/  
blah7/blah8/content4.fits/
```

file2.txt

```
content.fits  
content2.fits
```

I would now like to make a comparison of the two files based on the .fits extensions but write out the output to an ascii file keeping the formatting in file1.txt, i.e in this particular example the output file after comparing these two should give:

```
blah5/blah6/content3.fits/  
blah7/blah8/content4.fits/
```

any ideas?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ? diff command will show content of two files which are not in common.
here in your example blah/blah/content.fits/ and content2.fits will not considered in common.
check diff command first dude.

Comment: I guess you are more looking for pattern matching than diff.

Comment: Is `grep -vwf file2.txt file1.txt` what you want?

Comment: I'm looking to compare the two files and then write the difference to a third file, something like diff file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt, but I want to keep the format from file1.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk to get that output:

```
awk -F/ 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} !($(NF-1) in a)' file2.txt file1.txt
blah5/blah6/content3.fits/
blah7/blah8/content4.fits/
```